# The type or namespace name 'BookModel' does not exist in the namespace 'OutlierBookStore.Models' (are you missing an assembly reference), but it does

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTK3s.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CLjq.png)

I made a class inside my models folder, I've referenced the namespace in my _viewimports.cshtml as '@using OutLierBookStore.Models', I want access the class in my GetAllBooks.cshtml using @model,
I'able to access all other classes in my Models folder but not 'BookModel.cs' .

Comment: Can you provide your `ViewImports` if you still have a problem?

Comment: These are my mentioned directives in viewimports : 

using OutLierBookStore.Models

addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

Comment: @M_Aryan Check the correct spelling carefully in your ViewImports.it's obviously should work if you have not made a silly mistake in viewImports.Or you can post your full code of viewimports.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it should be working. Do you still have the problem if you save the file? I would comment this but I have no points.

Comment: Hello Dennis, I still have the same problem, but i have no clues why. 
My viewimports have these commands :
using OutLierBookStore.Models;     
addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check if the **namespace** of **BookModel.cs** is **OutLierBookStore.Models**.

- In other words, although the **BookModel.cs** you created is under the **Models** folder, **but** the **specified namespace** is **not** **OutLierBookStore.Models**, the error you prompted will appear.

  ```
   namespace OutLierBookStore.Models
   {
       public class BookModel
       {

       }
   }
  ```